# Different Picture is imported in the pdf

Tags: graphics, pdf

I use Texmaker with MikTex, and I am writing a file where I use a logo image as a background for the first page.
I put a folder (with name: data) in the same working directory, inside which the logo is located.
Strangely, other than importing the image from that folder, latex is importing a strange image from <<**C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\beautybook\inner_pics**>>.
Any explanations or solutions?

The piece of code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ data }
\usepackage[firstpage=true]{background}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Needed to define custom headers/footers
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\subsection\expandafter
    {\expandafter\@fb@secFB\subsection}%
  \newcommand\@fb@secFB{\FloatBarrier
    \gdef\@fb@afterHHook{\@fb@topbarrier \gdef\@fb@afterHHook{}}}%
  \g@addto@macro\@afterheading{\@fb@afterHHook}%
  \gdef\@fb@afterHHook{}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand{\bibTitle}[1]{``#1''}


\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Gets rid of all indentation
\backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo.png}},scale=0.5,placement=top,opacity=1,position={7.2cm,2cm}} %   Logo
\pagestyle{fancy} % Enables the custom headers/footers
\lhead{} \rhead{} % Headers - all  empty

\title{\normalfont \normalsize 
\textsc{School of   \\ 
Report} \\
[10pt] 
\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt} \\[8pt] 
\huge Title \\
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}  \\[10pt]
}
\author{Name \\ ID }
\date{\normalsize Submitted on Jul. 27\textsuperscript{th}}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are missing a brace pair in `\graphicspath{{data}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ooh I didn't notice it had graphicspath hmm

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I added a brace pair and nothing changed

Comment: and you should use `\includegraphics{./logo.png}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , Oh thank you, that worked ! I used \includegraphics{./logo.png} and it worked fine

Comment: @UlrikeFischer texlive omits the inner_pics directory, probably for this reason

Comment: it should be `\graphicspath{{data/}}` with `/` then you wouldn't need the `/` in the `\includegraphics`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I tried that before, and repeated my trial again  and it didn't solve it. Just using \includegraphics{./logo.png} worked

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no, you need the `./` to force the local search to take precedence.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer doesn't seem right but I'll take that offline:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle TeX Live has the `inner_pics` in the `doc` tree.

Comment: @cabohah yes, where they won't work but texlive never allows such generic names at runtime, the package will need to change

Answer (score 1):

Your `\graphicspath` setting is false, you need an additional brace and can also add a slash at the end (but it works for me also without it).

But the main point is to understand the search order: The code will at first use `kpsewhich` to search for the image and only if this fail check the pathes given by `\graphicspath`. That means that pictures in the current folder and in the texmf tree are found first and so preferred.

You can disable matches from the texmf tree by prepending `./` to the name. So

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{chapters/}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\includegraphics{./example-image}
\includegraphics{chapters/example-image}
\includegraphics{sub}
\end{document}
```

will find (assuming that I have example-image in the chapters folder)

```
<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.pdf> 
<./chapters//./example-image.pdf>
<./chapters/example-image.pdf>
<./chapters/sub.pdf>
```

Answer (score 0):

MikTex was importing a picture from ***inner_pics*** folder, but using `\includegraphics{./picture.png}` other than `\includegraphics{picture.png}` as commented by **UlrikeFischer** solved the problem.

Comment: IMHO the real solution would be to add braces and slash to the graphics path as explained in the manual and commented by David: `\graphicspath{{data/}}`.

Comment: @cabohah, as you see in the comments there, it didn't solve it.

Comment: @cabohah no, see e.g. https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1019#issuecomment-971417418

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But without the braces and the slash in graphicspath how can it find the `logo.png` in sub-directory `data`???? I've tested and it doesn't. It just results in: File `logo.png' not found

Comment: @cabohah yes, you need a correct graphicspath setting too, but the main point to avoid that the file in the texmf is found is to use ./logo in the includegraphics command.

Comment: So only changing the `\includegraphcs` argument does not solve the issue. It is a combination of two factors. Please show a complete solution not only one component.